# heroku - programmatically created file gets overwritten

Tags: git, heroku

i have an XML file which is written to my one of my codes. This activity works flawlessly ...until... i make a change to one of my PHP code files (any one) and do a git push. On doing this, my XML suddenly reverts back to the original file that i had uploaded.... meaning everything that was written by code is wiped clean. I know this is not logical and normal behaviour.... hence my question...what am i doing wrong? Do i have to make any settings on Heroku? my steps for uploading the changed file are as below.

```
    git add abc.php
    git commit -m "some comment"
    git push heroku master
```

all other uploaded files are fine... just this one which is affected programmatically. :(

Thanx in advance for the help.

Comment: but you just only uploaded `abc.php`. no XML uploaded. Did I misunderstand your question ?

Comment: @shivan raptor .... the xml was uploaded at an earlier point of time already. The above commands are issued after changing the existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you can make changes to files on Heroku they are not persisted across dynos, restarts or redeploys. Read more about the ephemeral filesystem that Heroku runs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

The only way to change a file on Heroku permanently is via a git push. If you need to change files then you need to use an external file store like Amazon S3 to write your files to and then retrieve them from there.

Comment: Thanx @john beynon ...this is the explanation that i was missing all this while. Now i need to re-look at my solution according to this new knowledge gained.